# Static directory not getting served

Tags: http, go, filesystems

I'm trying to serve a folder in the root of my application called `assets`. I want all files and subfolders within there to be accessible through the url `/details/`.

```golang
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets"))
http.Handle("/details/", http.StripPrefix("/details/", fs))
```

I still get 404s for everything. Am I using `StripPrefix` incorrectly?

To be clear, suppose `assets` contained `test.json`. I want that to be accessible from the URL `/details/test.json`.

Comment: Try `./details/` instead of `/details/`

Comment: As a test, try an absolute path to your assets directory. The above is a relative path - and if your go server is not in the same directory, it will not find it.

Comment: @Abdullah the `/details/` handler path is correct

Comment: @colminator Absolute path didn't help.

Comment: is there a user permission issue? i.e. what user is running the go-server and what file owership is on the assets directory?  Simplify your testing by pointing to /tmp/assets - and making all files/directories 'r-x'

Comment: @colminator shouldn't be a permission issue, I'm just running it locally.

Comment: There is no problem with the code you posted. I ran it and it works just Okay. Make sure you have no typo in your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the above comments double check your paths, permission, user contexts etc.

If you are still stuck, start with this basic setup:

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp/assets"))
        http.Handle("/details/", http.StripPrefix("/details/", fs))
        log.Fatal(
                http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil),
        )   
}
```

And test with curl etc.

```
$ find /tmp/assets

/tmp/assets
/tmp/assets/test.json

$ go run ./main.go

$ curl localhost:8080/details/

<pre>
<a href="test.json">test.json</a>
</pre>
```